# Reading from csv adding a new line to variabes - bash

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin

I am writing a bash script to read rows from csv and put them in variables. The read however is adding a new line to the variables. I tried removing them but it doesnt work.

In this case, ROW2 is Printing as -

```
Testing - line1
        - line2
```

However ROW1 is fine
My script:

```
sed '1d' export.csv | while IFS=,read -r ROW1 ROW2
do 
  ROW2=${ROW2%$'\n'}
  echo ROW2
done < export.csv
```

export.csv:

```
abc,Testing
```

Comment: Hi usr1234, would you please provide your input file?

Comment: Hi Mark, update the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ( I corrected some typos in your code ):

```
sed '1d' export.csv | while IFS=, read -r ROW1 ROW2
do 
  ROW1=${ROW1%$'\n'}
  echo $ROW1 $ROW2
done
```

Comment: Thankyou! I updated my script and still get the same issue 

Output - 

Testing - line 1
            - line 2

Answer (score 1):

This might work better for you assuming that you're deleting the first line of the file to avoid processing CSV headers:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=, read -r ROW1 ROW2
do
  echo $ROW1 $ROW2
done < <(sed '1d' export.csv)
```

This is using a technique called [process substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) to feed the output of the `sed` command into the input of `while`.

With that, I don't seem to have any issue with newlines in the variables.

You may be confusing the newline created by the `echo` command. For example, if we run the above script and pipe the output to `hexdump`, we can see what newlines actually exist:

```
# ./test.sh | hexdump -C
00000000  61 62 63 20 54 65 73 74  69 6e 67 0a              |abc Testing.|
```

There is one newline character present in the output (`0a`) and it is created by the echo command. To prove it, we can add the `-n` flag to the `echo` call (`echo -n $ROW1 $ROW2`) to suppress the newline:

```
# ./test.sh | hexdump -C
00000000  61 62 63 20 54 65 73 74  69 6e 67                 |abc Testing|
0000000b
```